# Apache Tomcat replacing the root servlet handler

Tags: tomcat, servlets

I must be missing something because I can't seem to get away from the "Hello World" servlet. I have a web.xml file set in my application's war file. I have a servlet and mapping that looks something like the following:

```
    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>root</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.api.json.POJOMappingFeature</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequestFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerResponseFilters</param-name>
        <param-value>com.sun.jersey.api.container.filter.GZIPContentEncodingFilter;my_package_path.CORSFilter</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
        <param-value>my_package_path.servlets</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>root</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

The problem is that when I hit the host_name/ URL, I get the "Hello World" app and not my servlet being called. I get the same problem with one level up from the root. What am I missing?

Comment: How is your webapp deployed (what is the name of its folder in `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps` folder)?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. I still think the configuration of the web.xml file should have overridden the index.jsp but did not. I was able to map most of the paths possible to my handler but then changed the index.jsp to simply redirect when the page was loaded.